# pymc3 negative binomial regression interpretation of mu and alpha

Tags: python, r, regression, logistic-regression, pymc3

I am confused about the interpretation for the negative binomial regression with python `pymc3` package. I am not sure how to interpret the `mu` and `alpha` in GLM. Here I have a simple vector, and I want to find the NB regression model for itself:

```
# The data
y = [100,200,300,400,50,300,60,89,90,100,100]
data = {'y':y, 'x':[1]*len(y)}
basic_model = pm.Model()
with basic_model:
    fml = 'y~x'
    pm.glm.GLM.from_formula(formula=fml, data=data, family=pm.glm.families.NegativeBinomial())
    # draw 500 posterior samples
    trace = pm.sample(500)
summary = pm.summary(trace, varnames=rvs)[['mean','hpd_2.5','hpd_97.5']]
print(summary)
```

Then I got output like:

```
                 mean     hpd_2.5    hpd_97.5
Intercept -281.884463 -684.069010  718.375125
x          287.000388 -714.168056  689.477911
mu          26.674426    3.526181   63.358150
alpha        2.461808    1.353676    3.452103
```

I understand that the `Intercept` & `x` part as `y = exp(-281.884463*287.000388*x)` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50031010/negative-binomial-regression-coefficient-interpretation).

But how to interpret the `mu` and `alpha`? I tried to use `stats.gamma.rvs(alpha, scale=mu / alpha, size=size)` but the histogram looks way off. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the `alpha` and the `mu` parameters are parameters of a [Exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) where `mu` is the mean and `alpha` is the gamma parameter. So in exponential distribution, 1/gamma is mean, and 1/(gamma^2) is the variance, if `mu` is mean that means the `mu / alpha` is the variance as stated in the `scale = mu / alpha` in the function call.

The way to think about it is something like this:

There is an interesting (key), relationship between the Poisson and Exponential distribution.  If you expect gamma events on average for each unit of time, then the average waiting time between events is Exponentially distributed, with parameter gamma (thus average wait time is 1/gamma), and the number of events counted in each unit of time is Poisson distributed with parameter gamma.

I hope this makes it a little more clear and gives you some intuition how to think about it.

Comment: Thank you so much! I read about the [poisson-gamma mixture](https://www.icpsr.umich.edu/CrimeStat/files/CrimeStatAppendix.D.pdf) after reading exponential distribution you mentioned. So the `mu` (not the `np.exp(mu)`) here would be the mean/expectation for dependent variable y, and `alpha` (not the `np.exp(alpha)`) would be the gamma shape parameter for all independent variables, which are hypothesized to be negative binomial distributed. But for dependent variables, like `x` here, the 'np.exp(x)' is the mean.

Comment: And `f = stats.gamma.rvs(alpha, scale=mu / alpha, size=size)` only give me a gamma distribution, if then use `stats.poisson.rvs(f)` would give me negative binomial distributed samples.